# If one option Selected disabled other selected option form all select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to disable same other option if one option selected. i have tried but not workig for me. bellow are my html select options and want to disable if one selected

```
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_2_slip_no" required="required">     
      <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
      <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
      <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
      <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
      <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
      <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
      <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
      <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
      <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_3_slip_no" required="required">     
      <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
      <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
      <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
      <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
      <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
      <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
      <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
      <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
      <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>

<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_4_slip_no" required="required">     
      <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
      <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
      <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
      <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
      <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
      <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
      <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
      <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
      <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_5_slip_no" required="required">     
      <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
      <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
      <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
      <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
      <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
      <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
      <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
      <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
      <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
```

This js code I have tried but not working

```
$('.input_slip_no').change(function(){

   alert('aaa');
    // start by setting everything to enabled
    $('select[name*="slip_no"] option').attr('disabled',false);

    // loop each select and set the selected value to disabled in all other selects
    $('select[name*="slip_no"]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
          $('select[name*="slip_no"]').not($this).find('option').each(function(){
           if($(this).attr('value') == $this.val())
               $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        });
    });

});
```

I am trying to disable select class change function but js not working.I don't know where I wrong.
disabled working of below answer but not able to insert selected data because of disabled value. is it possible to only alert. that this value already selected.

Comment: your code work fine https://jsfiddle.net/9vboppst/

Comment: i used bellow answered code that works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be done simply like :

```
$('.input_slip_no').on('change', function() {
    //Get selected options
    var selected_options = $('.input_slip_no').map(function(){
      return this.value
    }).get();

    //Disable the already selected options and enable others
    $('.input_slip_no option').each(function(index) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', $.inArray($(this).val(), selected_options) != -1);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.input_slip_no').on('change', function() {
  var selected_options = $('.input_slip_no').map(function(){
    return this.value
  }).get();

  $('.input_slip_no option').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', $.inArray($(this).val(), selected_options) != -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_2_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_3_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>

<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_4_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_5_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your code also disables the given option in the current selected drop-down

Comment: Yes, is that supposed to be a problem?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki the options are disabled but i also want to insert selected items. when it disabled not able to insert into database because of disabled.

Comment: What you want exactly to insert in the DB?